# Python Extract Text between two strings into Excel

Tags: python, excel, text

I have a text file like this

```
blablablabla
blablablabla
Start
Hello
World
End
blablabla
```

I want to extract the strings between Start and End and write them into an Excel cell. My code thus far looks like this:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Test1.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

flist = open("TextTest.txt").readlines()

parsing = False
for line in flist:

    if line.startswith("End"):
       parsing = False
    if parsing:
       worksheet.write(1,1,line)
    if line.startswith("Start"):
       parsing = True

workbook.close()
```

However it returns only an empty workbook. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much of a experience with excel stuff in python but you can try openpyxl, I found it much easier to understand.

Solution to your problem:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
destination_filename = "my.xlsx"
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "sheet1"
flist = open("text.txt").readlines()
row = 1
column = 'A'
parsing = False

for i in flist:      

    if i.startswith("End"):
        parsing = False
    if parsing:
        coord = column + str(row)
        ws[coord] = i
        row += 1        
    if i.startswith("Start"):
        parsing = True

wb.save(filename = destination_filename)
```

Edit(Writing all lines in one cell):

You have to create new variable to which you can add your lines, and at the end you will assign the string variable to cell in worksheet.

```
String=""
for i in flist:

    if i.startswith("End"):
        parsing = False    
    if parsing:
        i = i.strip("\n")
        String += str(i) + ","
    if i.startswith("Start"):
        parsing = True

ws['A1'] = String
wb.save(filename = destination_filename)
```

Comment: Works well! Just like my question below, what or where would I have to change something in the code if I wanted to write all the lines in one cell as opposed to one line in one cell?

Comment: Why you want to assign those lines into one cell ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you seem to be always writing in the line number 1

Second, the numeration starts at 0

With these two small changes, this should do what you want :

```
parsing = False
linewrite=0

for line in liste:

    if line.startswith("End"):
       parsing = False
    if parsing:
       worksheet.write(linewrite,0,line)
       print line,
       linewrite+=1
    if line.startswith("Start"):
       parsing = True

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Huge step forward, it now prints in the Excel! Is there a way I can write all the lines in one cell as opposed to every line in a new cell?

Comment: worksheet.write(0,0,sum([flist[flist.index('Start')+1:flist.index('End')])

Comment: It always returns  "SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier" for the second statement. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The data is being written to the cell, but one problem is that `worksheet.write()` will overwrite the contents of the cell, so only the last item written will be present.

You can solve this by accumulating the lines between `Start` and `End` and then writing them with one `worksheet.write()`:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Test1.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

with open("TextTest.txt") as data:
    lines = []
    for line in data:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "Start":
           lines = []
        elif line == "End":
            worksheet.write(0, 0, '\n'.join(lines))

workbook.close()
```

Here lines are accumulated into a list. When an end line is seen the contents of that list are joined with new lines (you could substitute this for another character, e.g. space) and written to the cell.

Comment: I see my mistake now but in your solution I also just get a blank worksheet. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: How are you viewing the spreadsheet? I've found that cells appear empty in LibreOffice if the content ends with a new line. Try enlarging cell A1. Does the example from http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/getting_started.html (Running a sample program) work for you?

Comment: Enlarging did the job! Perfect